# Form not being saved to vendors even though setup in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to save a vendor using a gravity form as the front end however i am not getting the record created the form does submit succefully though, i do have user registraction enabled though. I am using wordpress version 4.5.1 and plugin verison 5.3.7 of gravity forms.

I have treid everything I can think of for this but still is not working.

```
function wc_create_vendor_on_registration(  $entry, $form) {
$username = rgar( $entry, '6' );
$email    =rgar( $entry, '5' );
$description    =rgar( $entry, '2' );

// Ensure vendor name is unique
if ( term_exists( $username, 'shop_vendor' ) ) {
    $append     = 1;
    $o_username = $username;

    while ( term_exists( $username, 'shop_vendor' ) ) {
        $username = $o_username . $append;
        $append ++;
    }
}

// Create the new vendor
$return = wp_insert_term(
    $username,
    'shop_vendor',
    array(
        'description' => description ,
        'slug'        => sanitize_title( $username )
    )
);

if ( is_wp_error( $return ) ) {
    wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Unable to create the vendor account for this user. Please contact the administrator to register your account.', 'localization-domain' ), 'error' );
} else {
    // Update vendor data
    $vendor_data['paypal_email'] = $email; // The email used for the account will be used for the payments
    $vendor_data['commission']   = '50'; // The commission is 50% for each order
    $vendor_data['admins'][]     = $customer_id; // The registered account is also the admin of the vendor

    update_option( 'shop_vendor_' . $return['term_id'], $vendor_data );

    $caps = array(
        "edit_product",
        "read_product",
        "delete_product",
        "edit_products",
        "edit_others_products",
        "delete_products",
        "delete_published_products",
        "delete_others_products",
        "edit_published_products",
        "assign_product_terms",
        "upload_files",
        "manage_bookings",
    );

    $skip_review = get_option( 'woocommerce_product_vendors_skip_review' ) == 'yes' ? true : false;
    if( $skip_review ) {
        $caps[] = 'publish_products';
    }

    $caps = apply_filters( 'product_vendors_admin_caps', $caps );

    $user = new WP_User( $customer_id );
    foreach( $caps as $cap ) {
        $user->add_cap( $cap );
    }
}
}

add_action( 'gform_after_submission_1', 'after_submission', 10, 2 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer',    'wc_create_vendor_on_registration', 10, 2 );
?>
```

Comment: I'm not an expert on woocommerce but it looks to me like you're mixing up gravity forms and woocomerce action. What does your 'after_submission' function do? Is that where you register the user? I think the code in 'wc_create_vendor_on_registration' function needs to be in the gform_after_submission action. Could use more information though.

Comment: @dg4220 HI dg I have to save values from the form to the woocmerce vendors plugins so I need to use the wc_create vendor hook

Comment: You might get more help if you tag this as a  woocommerce question but, I have a couple of thoughts. Without seeing what's in your after_submission function I would look at either combining the contents of your wc_create_vendor_on_registration function with that - I don't know what triggers the woocommerce_created_customer action - or simply try add_action( 'gform_after_submission_1', 'woocommerce_created_customer', 10, 2 );. That ensures you're getting the $form and $entry data from the form.

Comment: @dg4220 thankyou dg yes if found the code on a blog and i couldnt find the after submission _1 so why was asking if i could get help with it here